# how to get current vm name/id from azure-cli within the vm?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-cli

how to tell from within the VM (Linux) in azure-cli who is this current VM ?
i try to understand it from UUID that i can see the UUID from https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/accessing-and-using-azure-vm-unique-id/ but how can i connect it to  a VM from the list command `az vm list -d -g resource_name`but the output does not include UUID or how to get the VM name from the CLI ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you best option is to just use the metadata endpoint:

```
curl -H Metadata:true "http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance/compute?api-version=2017-08-01"
```

this would return similar json:

```
{
  "compute": {
    "location": "CentralUS",
    "name": "IMDSCanary", <<< VM Name
    "offer": "RHEL",
    "osType": "Linux",
    "platformFaultDomain": "0",
    "platformUpdateDomain": "0",
    "publisher": "RedHat",
    "sku": "7.2",
    "version": "7.2.20161026",
    "vmId": "5c08b38e-4d57-4c23-ac45-aca61037f084",
    "vmSize": "Standard_DS2"
  }
}
```

Reading: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/instance-metadata-service#example-scenarios-for-usage

If you query the `http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance` endpoint you will also get subscription id, vm id, resource group, etc